# Touch Listeners for overlapping Views

Tags: android, view, touch, motion

I was wondering if it is possible to have Views sitting on top of each other and separate listeners for them. Specifically, I have two views that are exactly sitting on top of each other and are the exact same dimensions, and I'm trying to implement a motion event OnTouchListener for view_one and an OnLongPressListener for view_two. However, the OnTouchListener on view_one seems to block the OnLongClickListener for view_one.

The basic goal of the code is to have multiple touch interactions doing different things:

1. Short click does one thing
2. Long press does another
3. Touch drag and release in vertical direction does another thing
4. Touch-drag in horizontal another

Etc, as many different things as possible.

Maybe I should just have one View that is for touching rather than two, and there is a way to separate out the touches and motion events. I know how to separate short and long press events, but the motion event messes things up.

I'm sure there is a much better way to do this. Any hints or suggestions are much appreciated. Is there a way to put limits on the length of slide motion and touch duration that help determine which action to take?

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I'm new to this, so I'll work on the formatting more next time. Are comments like this are considered off topic and not allowed?

Comment: if the 2 views are of the same dimensions, why do you need to detect touches on both instead of just consuming the touches on the top view.  a long press on view 1 is the same as a long press on view 2, if they are of the exact same dimensions and location...

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct... I was just going about this all wrong. kyle's solution below solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question - if the touch listener is consuming the event before it reaches view_two (the underneath view), it may be because you are consuming the touch event in your [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html).

```
//Returns true if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.
public abstract boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event)
```

Are you always returning false in this method? If not, there are events that probably won't get propagated to the next view in the hierarchy.

As for your second question - yes, you certainly can create an [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to handle all of these events. Here's an example that does short and long press (independent of how much movement there is):

```
private MotionEvent downEvent;

public abstract boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event){
    if (downEvent == null && event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        downEvent = event;
        return false;
    }


    if (event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        if (event.getDownTime() > LONG_PRESS_THRESHOLD){
            ... do something ...
        } else if (event.getDownTime() > SHORT_PRESS_THRESHOLD){
            ... do something else ...
        } 
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, it will only take a bit more effort lines to determine if the delta X / delta Y between your down event and current event meets the threshold you determine for events 3 and 4.

Comment: Ok, that makes alot of sense. With some more googling and a lot of work I was able to get this implemented. Thanks!!! I think there are a couple of typos above: getAction(). I had to add the parentheses to get it to work. Also, getDownTime() gave me some trouble as that gives the system up time that the down event occurred, so I had to implement a getEventTime() to get the time that the up event occurred and then take the difference to compare to whatever threshold times I declare.